# Sinch not working on Safari browsers

Tags: safari, sinch

i implemented Sinch on my web application. Sinch is working fine on Google Chrome but when i opened it using Safari i get this error on my console - `Can't find variable: SinchClient`. It seems like Sinch does not work on Safari. Is there any solution for this problem? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work on safari browsers

Comment: thanks for the answer. so Sinch only works on Google Chrome?